# Java EE Scheduled task

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, weblogic, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a task to be run periodicily (e.g every 6 hours, or maybe everyday at 12 PM) on Weblogic 10.3 server. The task basically retrieves some data from the database and does some business logic with it.

What is the best way to achieve this? I have searched the internet, and found some solutions like:

- Using the Timer Service.
- Work Managers.
- EJB Timers.

And BTW, I am still learning JavaEE so maybe this is a basic question or I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running under a JavaEE container, you should avoid using the JDK's standard Timer feature. You should use EJB timers instead; favour those over any proprietary solution (I think that Work Managers are proprietary to WebLogic).

Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. BTW, I am using Weblogic 10.3.0 which runs JAVA EE 5. Creating EJB Timer via Eclipse requires EJB 3.1, which is not supported in Weblogic 10.3.0.

Comment: Hmmmm. EJB Timers were introduced with EJB 3.0, which WebLogic 10.3 supports. Where did you find out that Eclipse requires EJB 3.1 for creating timers?

Comment: It requires to include `javax.ejb.Schedule` annotation.

Comment: What about `javax.ejb.TimerService`?

Comment: How to configure the interval time with `javax.ejb.TimerService`?

Comment: This link seems to contain some useful examples: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/EJB3/UseTimerService.htm

Answer (score 1):

Consider  `javax.ejb.Schedule` annotation

Comment: Should I use it within an EJB? If yes, should I deploy it as session bean or entity bean?

Comment: BTW, I am using Webogic 10.3 which supports only EJB 3.0. `javax.ejb.Schedule` is introduced since EJB 3.1.

Comment: As for usage - better find some examples, there's a lot of them out there. As for EJB3.0, consider changing you application server to a EJB 3.1 compatible version, if it'spossible in your case. There are lots of good things in EJB 3.1. Schedule is just one example

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new MyTask(), 1000, 2000);
```

Comment: This is plain Java Code! How to deploy it on Weblogic?

Comment: Weblogic is also plain Java. But you shouldn't use Timer or any other manual threading technology in a JavaEE environment, you should use the features of the server. The EJB scheduling services of JEE6 in the case of replacing java util timer.